# What external screen size/resolution will make using Xcode on an 11 inch Air better?

Tags: xcode, display

I'm looking for an external LCD for my 11 inch Macbook Air (i5, 2013). The only thing I (am going to) use the Mac for is Xcode so the screen size needs to support development needs.

I hear the minimum decent resolution for Xcode is 1920x1080.

Is that enough or should I be looking for more pixels?

Comment: Good edit. I've re-opened the question.

Comment: @Ian C. -- This isn't about shopping - I'm simply asking if 1920x1080 is a decent resolution for Xcode and what screen size should I be looking for (e.g will 27" @ 1920x1080 look good or too big).

Comment: I attempted to add some more details - please correct the 11 inch vs 13 inch and also, if you can explain your role in developing (are you an indie developer doing everything or someone that's just doing QA / connecting code to interface items for a larger group and really need tons of pixels to have 4 or more windows visible at the same time.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is largely with either my old 17" MacBook Pro (1920 x 1200, 17") and 23" external monitors that run at 1920 x 1080.

First off, the extra 10% of vertical space makes a huge difference.

Secondly, I have found 1920 x 1200 to be fine, and it should be possible to get a screen at that resolution for your budget.

Thirdly, if you can get a 1920 x 1200 screen at 27" for $250, that sounds like a bit of a bargain.

23" is a fine size, and 1920 x 1080 is acceptable, with 1920 x 1200 preferred. You don't want 30" at 1920, but 27" should be OK.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at the pixel counts for the current iMacs since I've never heard of anyone that couldn't get substantial work done with the smaller but that most developers really appreciate the pixels of the larger iMac if they do substantial coding (6 hours a day or more).

http://www.apple.com/imac/specs/

The lower pixel count is 1920-by-1080 and the larger is 2560-by-1440

I've actually been productive on the 11 inch Air when traveling, but having a second display of any size was a big plus when at a desk to have code or documentation on the built in display and the app running on the larger screen (or the other way occasionally).

The fact that you have one use in mind for the Mac means you probably can do with less screen than someone that will also want to do communication, email, calendar as well as coding.

Comment: a + for sharing personal experience, while 11 inch is kind off small but light to carry :)